# How should I use wpdb class to submit a form in admin dashboard?

Tags: plugin-development

I want to create a plugin for the admin to write his everyday message in the dashboard & display it on his website. I have two files, `dailymessage.php` and `messageform.php`.

In `dailymessage.php` I have this code:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'getMessage' );
function getMessage() {
    add_options_page( "DailyMessage", "DailyMessage", 1, "DailyMessage", "messageForm" );
}
function messageForm() {
    include('messageForm.php' );
}
```

And in `messageform.php` I have this code:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <label for="adminMessage">Your Message : </label>
    <input id="adminMessage" type="text" name="adminMessage" placeholder="Your Message ..." />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>    
<?php
global $wpdb;
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();        
$sql = "CREATE TABLE messages (
    id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    message tinytext NOT NULL,
    ) $charset_collate;";        
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );        
$wpdb->insert( "messages", array(
    "id" => null,
    "message" => $_POST['adminMessage'],
) );
?>
```

The code is not working, why? Can I write my code for processing a form in the form file such as the above, or I should create another page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the [`Dashboard Widgets API`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API) you can use this code snippet that I have quickly concocted as a **starting point**:

```
function dashboard_daily_post_metabox() {
    add_meta_box( 'wt_id', 'Daily Post', 'dashboard_daily_post_process', 'dashboard', 'normal', 'high' );    
}
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'dashboard_daily_post_metabox' );

function dashboard_daily_post_process() {
    global $wpdb;
?>
    <form method="post">
        <label>Age <input type="text" name="wt_age" value="<?php echo $wpdb->prefix; ?>" /></label>
        <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Save" />
    </form>
<?php
}
```

As you can see you have access to the global `$wpdb` variable and you can process your request as you wish.

You can quickly test this code by dumping it in your theme's `functions.php` file.